# Creating my own clone of a Node.js package (with a bug fixed)

Tags: node.js, package, package-management

I am developing a project that depends on a buggy Node.js package. I can't wait till they fix the bug. So I want to fix the bug myself.

Please describe all steps necessary to create my own clone of their package where I can fix the bug.

Is it enough just to rename the package and upload it to nodejs.com? (How to upload?)

Any other variants?

Comment: It's enough to clone it and use a github link in your package.json. Duping a package globally to fix a bug just sows confusion.

Comment: @DaveNewton What is the format of github link?

Comment: ... https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json.html#github-urls